# Free In-App Purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm struggling with this. My client wants to set a price tag (£1.49) for the app and the app itself has 4 non-consumable in-app purchases as well (£1.49 each). However, they want to give one of the non-consumable free on the first run (but not a specific one, they want the user to choose from one of those 4) because they have paid for the application.

Is there any way to manage this? As far as I know, we cannot create free non-consumable product in iTunes connect. We can check if that's the first time user and unlock the product programmatically, but since this won't be through iTunes Connect, the users won't be able to carry their unlocked feature to other devices..

If we happen to use our own server and database to track who unlocked which as free, then I think the app more likely to be rejected.

One solution might be to make the app free and keep the non-consumables as same, but client is not keen on that solution.

Can you please advise?

Thanks
Oz

Comment: I'd love to see a decent solution to this.  I have the same problem right now except we're selling hardware and we'd like to offer one of our IAP for free per hardware purchased.  This would work beautifully if IAP supported free purchases.  It's a lot of work to put up the infrastructure to do it ourselves.  Also...  not sure how to identify users.  We want to identify by user (i.e. apple id) not by device.

Comment: I don't know how to identify user either. I will add here if I find a solution.

Comment: Well you can't, unless you offer some sort of sign up process. Less likely for users to use your gift if they need to provide their name / email address first, though. Other than that there's the game center ID, but using that feels awkward and you can't assume everyone is registered for game center.

Comment: Ya, signup process is messy too.  People could all easily use the same username / password.  Unlike apple id, username wouldn't be tied to a credit account or devices, so there's no reason not to share it with people.  Not to mention as you pointed out, user doesn't want to have to create yet another login - and I'm with them there.  No good solution.  I think I'll end up just highly discounting products by having two sku's point to same product and the second sku is minimum price of $0.99.  Just so much easier that way.  Just have to get management to approve.

Comment: Don't know the answer. But you could look at [ubiquityIdentityToken](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/ubiquityIdentityToken) as a possible way to identify a user. Not all users will be signed into iCloud though.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that won't work.

At least not using the appstore itself. You might be able to offer a way to download / access the same content though by implementing a seperate infrastructure which manages free download eligibility. For example, the app, upon the first launch, might check with your server if the device it is running on has been registered already. If not, it registers itself with your server and grants the user free access to one of the products.

After using up the free product, purchases are processed through IAP as usual. You would need to take care however that the user may not accidentially purchase a product again after it has been downloaded for free, and that re-installing the app won't give the same user another free download.

This way would require considerably more work and you'd loose the safety of Apples IAP structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just thought about the same solution, except registering the user with the server.. I will give it a go.